# How to get the current caret position in a contenteditable div in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios

I want to insert a image into a contentedible div in a UIWebView.

However, in iOS 7, when keyboard shows, the UIWebView loses focus. Thus I have to record the caret position before showing the keyboard, and then insert the image at that position.

Could anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you able to get caret position ?